# Loading images in Listview at once

Tags: android, listview

I am having very difficult time understanding all the processes (in google and SO) of loading image in list view. However, I manage to get the system working [following example here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/).

<strike>But the images loaded are per view and when I change the view (scroll), it loads again</strike> [I guess it is the system]. **And more important issue is, you can see image below, I have partial view of book number 11 at the bottom, hence the image is loaded for top book (book#1). If I scroll down and then go top again, then Book#1 loads that default grayish image, as expected ... so this problem happens only during first time load**

<strike>Is it possible to load the images AT ONCE for all the lists in the background task so that everytime I scroll, it does not load new images</strike>? How can I tackle the problem mentioned in the image below?

I have made some modification with kind help of one SO member to include a checkbox though. Below is the changed part from the example. Rest classes (ImageLoader, MemoryCache, Utils, FileCache) are exactly copy from the example above.

[image]

**Base Adapter Class** [changed from the example]

```
public class MyList extends BaseAdapter {

    static HashSet<String> selectedBooks = new HashSet<String>();
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public MyList(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener checkChangedListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            String bookId = (String) buttonView.getTag();
            if(isChecked){
                selectedBooks.add(bookId);
            }else{
                selectedBooks.remove(bookId);
            }
        }
    };

    public static String[] getSelectedBooks(){
        return selectedBooks.toArray(new String [selectedBooks.size()]);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        //return position;
        return data.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        //return position;
        return Long.parseLong(data.get(position).get(ShowList.LIST_KEY_ID));
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView writer;
        TextView bookid;
        CheckBox check;
        ImageView thumb;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.writer = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.writer);
            holder.bookid = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookid);
            holder.thumb = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumb);
            holder.check = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.check);
            holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkChangedListener);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        HashMap<String, String> book = (HashMap<String, String>) getItem(position);
        holder.check.setTag(book.get(ShowList.LIST_KEY_ID));
        holder.title.setText(book.get(ShowList.LIST_KEY_NAME));
        holder.writer.setText(book.get(ShowList.LIST_KEY_WRITER));
        //holder.thumb.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_cover);
        holder.bookid.setText(book.get(ShowList.LIST_KEY_ID));
        if(!book.get(ShowList.LIST_ISBN).trim().equals("")){
            Log.d("name","NAME: "+book.get(ShowList.LIST_KEY_NAME));
            Log.d("isbn","ISBN: "+book.get(ShowList.LIST_ISBN));
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(book.get(ShowList.LIST_ISBN), holder.thumb);
        }
        boolean bookSelected = false;
        if(selectedBooks.contains(book.get(ShowList.LIST_KEY_ID))){
            bookSelected = true;
        }
        holder.check.setChecked(bookSelected);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview) will Help you and all to explore More.

Answer (score 0):

Use lazy load list.

```
ImageLoader imageLoader =new ImageLoader(this);
imageLoader.DisplayImage(imageURL, ImageView);
```

URL :https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Comment: I guess I am doing the same thing :-s

Answer (score 0):

Write else part for the image that you set:

```
 if(!book.get(ShowList.LIST_ISBN).trim().equals("")){
            Log.d("name","NAME: "+book.get(ShowList.LIST_KEY_NAME));
            Log.d("isbn","ISBN: "+book.get(ShowList.LIST_ISBN));
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(book.get(ShowList.LIST_ISBN), holder.thumb);
        }else{
        holder.thumb.setImageResource(<DefaultImage>);


}
```

Comment: do you have some image that u show in case of book-1?? or it's default one

Comment: nope .. for Book#1, LIST_ISBN is "" (empty), and I have already default_image loaded in xml for each row. Also, interesting thing is, if I scroll down once and then again go top, then Book#1 has that default grayish image, as expected ... so this problem happens only during first time load

Answer (score 0):

solved the issue just by changing layout_weight & layout_height= "fill_parent" ...